# Is it acceptable for moderators to legislate new policies?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderation, rules

A while back, in their Meta Stack Exchange post [Moderators are Police Officers, not Politicians](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291656/336163), anonymous2 mentioned regarding ♦ moderators:

> Our job is to enforce the law, not to define it. If a change in the law is necessary, the community must have their voice - even if it is a moderator who proposes the change. In some cases, it will be up to community managers to implement a change...

In my own service as a ♦ moderator, I've attempted to live this principle. I am a judge, not a legislator. I often need to *interpret* an existing policy such as the Code of Conduct, but I do not come up with my own policies, either on my own or in concert with the other moderators on my site.

This principle seems to have been broken with Stack Overflow's [Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/6471538), apparently implemented either in the name of Makyen's diamond or in the name of the ♦ moderators of Stack Overflow.

The policy reads in part as follows (emphasis mine):

> If a user is believed to have used ChatGPT after this temporary policy is posted, **sanctions will be imposed** to prevent users from continuing to post such content, **even if the posts would otherwise be acceptable.**

This crosses the line between a moderator interpreting network policy (e.g. deciding what constitutes spam, hate speech, or gibberish in the context of their community) and creating a brand new rule that no reasonable user could interpolate from existing network polices. An answer generated with ChatGPT is apparently now ban-worthy even if it answers the question, is high quality, and includes appropriate citations to ChatGPT and any other appropriate sources.

In other words, there is nothing in the Code of Conduct or any other network-wide policy that puts a reader on notice that an answer that would otherwise be acceptable (answers the question, attributes all sources, doesn't consist solely of unintelligible gibberish, isn't a dietary supplement ad masquerading as an answer, etc.) is problematic *solely* because ChatGPT was used as an aid to its creation. Users who don't regularly read Meta (which I dare say is a high percentage of casual users) will likely have no notice of this new rule and thus be at risk of violating it without awareness that they are at risk of negative action against their account.

Now, I do not doubt that the issue addressed by the ChatGPT ban is important, emergent, and and quite possibly serious enough to possibly merit the network granting an [exception](https://www.starwars.com/video/emergency-powers). What I am questioning is the general process.

Should moderators, either alone or as a team, be allowed to implement new policies and take official moderator action against those who violate them? My fear here is that if moderators are granted legislative authority over their sites, we will see rule fragmentation where users familiar with the network's policies will join a new site, inadvertently violate a site-specific policy, and get suspended.

In response to Anton Menshov, I am primarily asking about the general case, whether moderators should be allowed to legislate their own policies and then ban users who violate them. For example, if another network site experiences a sudden rush of expertly-disguised spam from Guatemalan IP addresses and the site's moderation team decides to implement a policy that any user with less than 100 rep logging in from an IP address that resolves to Guatemala will be summarily suspended regardless of whether they post spam out of a fear that they might post spam later, would this be an acceptable moderator action or an overstep potentially leading to [action against the offending moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336173/336163)?

Comment: Currently, this question lacks focus: are you talking about nullifying a particular ChatGPT policy? Are you talking about the ability of users to see site-specific rules? Are you interested in a discussion if moderators can create (and under which circumstances) new policies? All 3 questions could be very valid (with some probably having reasonably-close duplicates), but together I am not seeing a reasonable way to even start answering/discussing it.

Comment: @AntonMenshov I am asking about the general case of whether moderators should be allowed to legislate. My references to the ChatGPT issue are to support my case as to why this needs to be discussed now.

Comment: Much like how the U.S. President can impose executive orders to quickly resolve serious issues that come up and need immediate resolution without having to go through Congress to pass the law which takes time, I'd say it's fair for moderators to pass *temporary* policies pending the outcome of discussions.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog What on earth has a diamond mod to do with the US president? That has to be the worst analogy I read today, and I'm currently grading philosophy 101 coursework.

Comment: @Akixkisu: Likely because the ***disproportionate*** coverage of US politics by the world's media, incl. [actions by former presidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_privilege#Trump_administration) (not that it isn't important; it is), it is the first that comes to mind.

Comment: If it saves this place from becoming a giant pile of garbage, yes, absolutely. This response was in line with keeping this a repository of useful knowledge. Curation and moderation wasn't able to keep up with it even before it happened, and this makes things much worse. It's rather sad the corporation hasn't responded to this crisis yet. It's as if nothing happened.

Comment: FWIW I pressured the SO mod team 12 hours prior to the Meta post to put a post up. Not sure why it took them so long to stop/ban something that is clearly harming the community.

Comment: Kinda hope the swiftly instated temporary ban is made permanent.

Comment: @DanMašek The Stack Exchange staff are working on it. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384396/ban-chatgpt-network-wide#comment1282259_384396

Comment: Super User has had a policy barring hackintosh questions dating  from before I was a mod, set by the mod team at the time, there's precident and a fair amount of leeway afforded to moderators to deal with things like this.

Answer (score 21):

I know you want a general answer, but I don't think it's particularly fair to ask for one.

It's clear this is a bit of a special case, with a recent and *extreme* uptick in a particular type of answer. SO moderators already have a mandate to act against users repeatedly posting low-quality content, and to remove plagiarism. ChatGPT content has a high probability to violate these (possibly guaranteed on the latter point).

To use a legislative analogy, it's a bit like the difference between *law* and *code*. The *law* says no plagiarism and no junk content; *code* tells you that ChatGPT content will be considered to belong to those categories. I'd interpret this as communication from the moderators on how they're interpreting things - I think that communication is a good thing.

I don't think this is a move taken lightly, clearly the SO mods as a team have been in communication with each other on this and saw this as a necessary step to maintain the site.

It seems pretty clear from votes and answers that the Meta community at SO supports that decision at this point, and there's no community consensus against it.

Answer (score 13):

Extraordinary problems may require extraordinary solutions.

Having hundreds of people suddenly post dozens of nonsense answers each, none of which are obviously nonsense at first glance is not something that's really happened before. We've had spam waves but spam is somewhat easy to spot and spammers tend not to be able to create more than one or two answers before they are caught and dealt with.

If those people continued unchecked then we'd have almost all new posts having multiple useless answers. It wouldn't be long before Stack Overflow wasn't fit for purpose i.e. it didn't help anyone, it just wasted their time.

So moderators need to be able to do whatever it takes to keep a site functional and useful. In the long term they do need to make sure they keep their community on board - otherwise they won't have a community. But in the short term, we've elected them because we trust them to do what it takes.

There are already different rules for different sites. Some allow recommendations, most don't. Some allow identification of things, many don't. That's in part why we have different sites, to allow that variation. If you're active in multiple sites you do come to understand that and adapt to each sites foibles.

There's no evidence that moderators have introduced arbitrary rules such as the ones you've suggested and if they did your ultimate recourse is to appeal to the CMs via [Contact Us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact).

Answer (score 8):

> I am a judge, not a legislator.

[Separation of powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_powers) is the right principle!

> This principle seems to have been broken with Stack Overflow's Temporary policy: ChatGPT is banned

I think this falls under ***daily operations*** (with some emergency) and the community was fast to give an unambiguous consensus (+850 votes in 24 hours) lending their authority to the policy.

> My fear here is that if moderators are granted legislative authority over their sites

Adding to the many arguments already I think it's important to mention the decision is a circumstanced continuation of existing policies (regarding low quality content) instead of a change in policy that breaks with previous practices - in that sense it comes without surprise.

Comment: I think you've hit a really important note– on its face, "ban of ChatGPT answers" sounds very drastic, and like something that a good actor might accidentally trip over and be banned for. In practice, this fight is against folks who are knowingly producing total garbage with this tool, and refusing to verify that their posts are accurate, which was _already not allowed_, regardless of the circumstances or tooling that existed before ChatGPT. I like how you called it a "continuation of existing policies", I think that's perfectly apt.

Answer (score -1):

We're the folks on the ground, and and much like [Sam Vimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sam_Vimes), our soles are thin, and we know our sites by the feel of the cobblestones.

Practically - a lot of the time, moderators are the first responders to any issue and aware of the full extent of the problems faced and mitigations. While we're better off historically in terms of community managers, its quicker to make a decision, set a policy, let them know *then* review it, and well, since there's less clean up, is easier for all involved.

To quote '[A theory of moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)'

> Even with active community self-regulation, moderators occasionally need to intervene. Moderators are human exception handlers, there to deal with those (hopefully rare) exceptional conditions that should not normally happen, but when they do, they can bring your entire community to a screaming halt — if you don’t have human exception handling in place.

and based off this making these policy decisions *is* part of what a moderation team needs to be free to do.

And to quote its [sequel](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/)

> Give people as much agency as you can. The people closest to the issues tend to be the ones that are best suited to make the best decisions.

and

> **Autonomy is critical to a sense of ownership.** Folks need high-level direction in order to thrive, but even more essential is the space to interpret goals and distill them out into a strategy that they can act on in their own very unique circumstances.

While, after a decade and change, the need to create new policies is uncommon, the *freedom* of moderators to make these decisions is actually a critical part of the moderation system. While the community team *facilitates* community moderation functions, on every site, much of the moderation and decision making is by the community and moderation team

As such, in a situation where its needed, moderation teams *need* to be free to create new policies to resolve a situation where the current rules may not be sufficient. Its not just 'acceptable' - its 'necessary'